# When and where does splitting happen?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

For example I have a 1 Gb file in HDFS like

```
2018-10-10 12:30  
EVENT INFORMATION  
2018-10-10 12:35  
ANOTHER EVENT INFORMATION  
...
```

So I need to use `NLineInputFormat` (N = 2), right?
The question is about more conceptual principles. When and where is this 1 Gb file transformed into `InputSplits`? How does hadoop handle different splitting logic? Does it need to parse the whole file to create splits (because we need to go through the file to count lines one-by-one)?
This file is divided into 8 blocks in HDFS (1024 / 128). So, when I submit a job hadoop starts mapper on each node with the blocks for this file (with default split size).

What will happen if my file isn't divided neatly? Like

```
<block1>
...
2018-10-10 12:
</block1>
<block2>
40
EVENT INFORMATION
...
</block2>
```

How will first mapper know about remaining part that is located on another datanode?

What happen if split size = 1/2 block size? Or 4/5 block size? How does application master know which node should it pick to run a split?

Can you please make it clear and give me some links to get it more deeply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division of data ( the division of File into Block), this is physically  true division
Split and HDFS Block are one to many relationships;

HDFS block is the physical representation of data, while Split is the logical representation of data in block.

In the case of data locality, the program also reads a small amount of data from remote nodes, because rows are cut to different Block.

when  you read  a file  , it is like this

[image]

The client opens the file by calling the open() method of the FileSystem object (corresponding to the HDFS file system and calling the DistributedFileSystem object) (that is, the first step in the figure). The DistributedFileSystem calls the NameNode through the RPC (Remote Procedure Call) call to get this. The file location of the first few blocks of the file (step 2). For each block, the namenode returns the address information of all the namenodes that have this block backup (sorted by the distance from the client in the topology network of the cluster. See the following for how to perform the network topology in the Hadoop cluster).

> If the client itself is a datanode (if the client is a mapreduce
>   task) and the datanode itself has the required file block, the client
>   reads the file locally.

After the above steps are completed, DistributedFileSystem will return an FSDataInputStream (support file seek), the client can read data from FSDataInputStream. FSDataInputStream wraps a DFSInputSteam class that handles I/O operations for namenodes and datanodes.
The client then executes the read() method (step 3), and the DFSInputStream (which already stores the location information of the first few blocks of the file to be read) is connected to the first datanode (that is, the most recent datanode) to get the data. By repeatedly calling the read() method (fourth and fifth steps), the data in the file is streamed to the client. When the end of the block is read, the DFSInputStream closes the stream pointing to the block, and instead finds the location information of the next block and then repeatedly calls the read() method to continue streaming the block.
These processes are transparent to the user, and it appears to the user that this is an uninterrupted streaming of the entire file.
When the entire file is read, the client calls the close() method in FSDataInputSteam to close the file input stream (step 6).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you please clarify how does application master assign InputSplit to particular execution node (NodeManager)? For example InputSplit A is linked to Block A and Block B. Both blocks are on different datanodes. Where will Map task run?

Comment: @ВадимПарафенюк  the data's location  can't decide  where  the map should run  , the map get data as nearly as  it can  . local ,near server ,other rock ..,   each  inputSplit  generate a map  .  so  Where  map  to run depends on server resources & resourcemanager

Comment: I got the idea that map tries to pick the nearest data, but it's not clear where an inputSplit generates a map task. InputSplits are generated by application master, right? So it has to generate a map task for particular node...
Or just there are for example 10 input splits, so 10 map tasks are generated by app master and this tasks try to pick the nearest data (but how do they decide which InputSplit they should pick). I am a little bit confused :)

Comment: For example I have 100 nodes and want to do mapreduce for the file that fits 1 block (replication = 1). Is it possible that Map task will be assigned to the node that doesn't contain this file (all nodes are free and healthy), I mean is this assignment random?

Comment: As I can see from the source code of FileInputFormat, each split contains information about exactly one block (hosts with this block and hosts that cache this block). So it's more clear now. Now the question is how InputSplits are assigned to the map task and how this map task are allocated (randomly or using the information about data blocks)

Comment: this is a  good  question  ,it is not  randomly  , but  it is also  hard to say  what is the algorithm .  it  according to 'numActiveTrackers' ,'heartbeat status'   ,'load situation' ,‘ capacity’ ，‘file location’   and so on  , both  of them is  a factor for  deciding where the  mapper  started

Comment: According  to your condition  ,if there are no differences in other conditions, it  runs local priority

Comment: Thanks :) The main is that the application master takes the information about block location for each InputSplit into account. Now my puzzle is completed :)

Comment: glad to  help you  the  inputsplit  also  contains the informations about the  block location .